# List all files in a directory - filter by size

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to to get all files which are larger then 20kb.
I tried the following but it returns all files, even when they are smaller then 20kb:

```
dir = 'C:\\some\\path'
filter(lambda x:os.path.getsize>20000L, [os.path.join(dir, x) for x in os.listdir(dir)])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression inside the lambda is not using its argument. In fact,

```
lambda x: os.path.getsize > 20000
```

compares the function `getsize` to an integer. That should be:

```
lambda x: os.path.getsize(x) > 20000
```

Comment: Thanks.. didnt notice that. so whats the difference between 20000L and 20000?

Comment: The suffix `L` in a literal makes it a [long integer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) explicitly. Long integers don't have size limits, but it is not relevant for numbers like `20000`.

Answer (score 2):

To print files that are larger than 20kb:

```
import glob
import os

for fyle in glob.glob('*'):
    if os.stat(fyle).st_size > 20000:
        print fyle, os.stat(fyle).st_size
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all files larger than 20000

```
>>>import os
>>>dir = 'C:\\some\\path'
>>>[(path +file) for file in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.getsize(file) > 20000]
```

Comment: os.listdir will just return the file name and not the full path.